# Unscrupulous apps on iTunes -- bank account hacked by iTunes merchant?

Tags: iphone, itunes, security

I recently had $500 stolen from my bank account via the iTunes store. I am not certain whether the charges are directly from Apple or via some other company whose iPhone app has somehow circumvented whatever security is on the system.

The specifics are that I had 3 phantom charges amounting to just under $500 on my credit card, but *there were no charges on my itunes statement!*

<sup>Apple of course will not even look at the case. It is the job of 'local law enforcement and credit card companies to assure that your account has not been compromised'.</sup>

I am looking for somewhere that has compiles/maintains a list of unscrupulous/hacked/hacking iphone apps so that I can compare the applications that are on my phone with untrustworthy ones.  Also, if anyone has advice with respect to cutting through the bureaucracy and receiving real support from Apple, that would be appreciated.

NOTE: Manually migrated from [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/173585/is-there-a-list-of-dishonest-iphone-apps)

Comment: Have you checked your iTunes purchase history to see if the charges on your credit card are associated with your account or if someone just stole your credit card number?

Comment: Well, it seems that maybe someone stole my credit card number and used it to charge iTunes, which would be a very strange thing for them to do, imho, unless they stole my credit card number from iTunes in the first place

Comment: @Mechko: Why would that be a strange thing for them to do? Thieves don't want music?

Comment: well they wouldn't want 40 copies of the same 160 songs/apps on 40 different accounts.  But if they managed to actually STEAL my credit card details through iTunes, I would imagine that they would siphon the money elsehow so as not to draw attention to their potentially profitable exploit.

Answer (score 4):

Forget about working with Apple. Just tell your credit card company.

Comment: On it.  Except I'm overseas.... :(

Comment: that shouldn't stop you. most credit card companies have toll numbers that they let you call collect, or local numbers in many countries that are free or cheap to call. or log in to the web page of your credit card and dispute it from there.